# Как засечь время открытия файла программой с помощью компьютерного зрения?

Tags: python, bash, cmd, bat, autohotkey

Имею ввиду время с момента запуска файла до появления окна с интерфейсом программы.
Я хочу измерить скорость открытия картинок разными просмотрщиками. Но на глаз это делать не комильфо.
Я думаю, что это можно сделать как-то с помощью скрипта с компьютерным зрением, но не знаю как. Может есть какие-то подсказки или решения, что использовать и как.

Comment: Тут очень много параметров нужно учитывать: от забитости процессора с ОЗУ до особенностей самих приложений. Может быть на глаз в этом случае и не самая плохая идея, особенно если не важна точность выше 0.1с

Comment: Можно записывать видео экрана и потом в редакторе отмерить время. Я думаю, такое решение вполне подойдёт, если не требуется сверхвысокая точность.